# Saving a Button's Image State Across Different Views

Tags: swift

My app is a Tableview Controller with cells that contain a fictional character's name. When a cell is selected, a View Controller with specific details about the character is brought up. I want the user to be able to mark off each character that they already own.

I set up the following code to toggle between an empty circle image and a filled circle image to represent whether the user owns the character or not.

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
var setImageStatus: String = "off" {
    willSet {
        if newValue == "on" {
            ownedCheck.image = UIImage(named: "filledCircle.jpg")
        } else {
            ownedCheck.image = UIImage(named: "emptyCircle.jpg")
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func ownedButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    let stat = setImageStatus == "on" ? "off" : "on"
    setImageStatus = stat
    defaults.set(stat, forKey: "imgStatus")
}   

if let imgStatus = defaults.string(forKey: "imgStatus")
    {
        setImageStatus = imgStatus
    } else {
        setImageStatus = "off"
    }
```

The problem I am having is that once the ownedButton is clicked, the circle stays filled in for every character. Is there a way to make the button be unique for each character?

I can't post an image yet, so here is a screenshot of the tableview code. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vShVA.jpg

Comment: share some screenshots. what do your `tableView` datasource functions do? share that too

Comment: but from the code you have already shared, it looks like you would require some serious structural improvements. example 1: `setImageStatus` is a string instead of bool. example 2: you are saving this `imgStatus` but no mechanism to figure for which character. well... technically you can do things this way but it's just a painful and inelegant path that you are planning to take.

Comment: @staticVoidMan I added a link to a screenshot of the tableView functions. The cells get their data from a JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

You can approach your problem by storing the Characters Name and It's associated Button in a Dictionary:

```
//1. Create A Dictionary With The Character's Name As The Key & The Button As The Value
var characterButtonInformation = [String: UIButton]()
```

Then you can get reference to the Buttons and handle the checking easily. Here is a crude example, where if a button has the title on, it will change colour:

```
    //1. Create Dummy Buttons With A Unique Title (Could Use Tag As Well)
    let buttonOne = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
    buttonOne.titleLabel?.text = "On"
    buttonOne.backgroundColor = .green
    self.view.addSubview(buttonOne)

    let buttonTwo = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 220, width: 100, height: 100))
    buttonTwo.titleLabel?.text = "Off"
    buttonTwo.backgroundColor = .green
    self.view.addSubview(buttonTwo)

    //2. Add These To The Dictionary
    characterButtonInformation["Frodo"] = buttonOne
    characterButtonInformation["Bilbo"] = buttonTwo

    //3. Check The Values For The Characters
    for character in characterButtonInformation{

        print("""
        Character = \(character.key)
        Button Title = \(character.value.titleLabel!.text)
        """)

        //4. Handle The State
        if character.value.titleLabel?.text == "On"{
            character.value.backgroundColor = .cyan
        }
    }
```

You can then pass this data to another ViewController which has its own `[String: UIButton]` Dictionary.

**Update:** Since your are using JSON (which wasn't shown earlier) it will be easier to store your Characters in a `Codable struct' e.g:

```
  ///Structure Used To Store Character Data From JSON
     struct Character: Codable {

     var characterName: String!
     var isOwned: Bool!
     var hasMagicPowers: Bool!
  }
```

Ideally this would be best suited as being saved in CoreData, due to the size of your data.

A basic setup of the MainViewController therefore could be like so:

```
    class ViewController: UITableViewController {

//1. Array To Store All The Characters
var characters = [Character]()

//2. Currently Selected Character
var characterToShow: Character!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    //1. Fake Data
    let frodo: Character = Character(characterName: "Frodo", isOwned: true, hasMagicPowers: false)
    let bilbo: Character = Character(characterName: "Bilbo", isOwned: false, hasMagicPowers: false)
    let gandalf: Character = Character(characterName: "Gandalf", isOwned: true, hasMagicPowers: false)
    characters.append(frodo)
    characters.append(bilbo)
    characters.append(gandalf)


    super.viewDidLoad()

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() { super.didReceiveMemoryWarning() }

//-------------------------------------
//MARK: TableViewDataSource & Delegates
//-------------------------------------

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return characters.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CharacterCell
    cell.characterName = characters[indexPath.row].characterName

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let indexPath = indexPath.row
    characterToShow = characters[indexPath]
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showCharacter", sender: self)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    //1. Get The Character DetailView
    let characterDetailView = (segue.destination as! CharacterDetailViewController)

    //2. Set The Character Details
    characterDetailView.characterDetails = characterToShow

   }

 }
```

Then in your CharacterDetailView handle the Character Data as you need e.g:

```
class CharacterDetailViewController: UIViewController {

var characterDetails: Character!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let characterOwnedButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 66, width: 100, height: 100))
    characterOwnedButton.backgroundColor = .cyan
    characterOwnedButton.titleLabel?.text = "Not Owned"

    if characterDetails.isOwned{
        characterOwnedButton.titleLabel?.text = "Owned"
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

   }
}
```

Of course you need to manage the persistence of your data etc, but this should be more than enough to point you in the right direction.

Comment: There are currently about 1,500 entries, so does that mean by doing it this way that I would have to make 1,500 separate let buttonXxxx = ... expressions?

Comment: Updated based on your inclusion of JSON as your data source, and the number of Characters you have.

Answer (score 0):

Following your logic, I would suggest a slight modification to the way you use `UserDefaults` to identify that the character is "owned".

```
var setImageStatus: Bool = false {
    willSet {
        if newValue {
            //Update UI
            ownedCheck.image = UIImage(named: "filledCircle.jpg")

            //Save state to user defaults
            defaults.set(newValue,
                         forKey: character.id)
        }
        else {
            //Update UI
            ownedCheck.image = UIImage(named: "emptyCircle.jpg")

            //Minor Optimization: Remove state from user defaults
            defaults.removeObject(forKey: character.id)
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func ownedButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    //Simply toggle the state, the variable's willSet will handle the rest
    setImageStatus = !setImageStatus
}

//Call this method from viewDidLoad
func checkIfCharacterIsSelected() {
    //Simply retrieve the state, the variable's willSet will handle the rest
    setImageStatus = defaults.bool(forKey: character.id)
}
```

So basically, we store a simple `bool` against some unique identifier of the character to check if it is "owned" or not.
In my example, I have assumed your `character` object has an `id` variable which is of type `String` and hence doing the following would work:

- `defaults.bool(forKey: character.id)`
- `defaults.set(newValue, forKey: character.id)` bits.

However, `UserDefaults` should not be used carelessly to store junk.
You mentioned your JSON could have 1500 characters! I'd definitely not recommend `UserDefaults` and I'd say this data should come from a server or a JSON stored on disk holding this information. But it is now your responsibility to find a way that suits you.

try? Read: https://medium.com/@deepcut/understanding-ios-data-persistence-nsuserdefaults-and-the-file-system-cf062dc53761